# How to use try except statement in python to handle non numeric inputs

Tags: python, try-except

Please tell me what is wrong with it. because when I run this it tells an error. at line" if hrs > 40" and says its a syntax error!

```
while true:
    hrs = input ("Enter no.of hrs worked: ")
    rate = input ("Enter the rate per hour: ")
    try:
        hrs = int(hrs)
        rate = int(rate)
        raise ValueError("Non numeric value")
    except enter code hereValueError as e:
        print (e)
        continue
if hrs > 40
    # anything over 40 hrs earns the overtime rate
    overtimeRate = 1.5 * rate
    overtime = (hrs-40) * overtimeRate
    # the remaining 40 hrs will earn the regular rate
    hrs = 40
    regular=hrs*rate
    total_pay=regular+overtime
    print(total_pay)
    else:
        # if you didn't work over 40 hrs, there is no overtime
        overtime = 0
        total_pay=hrs*rate
        print(total_pay)
  quit()
```

Comment: You need a colon there: `if hrs > 40:`.

Comment: You also need to unindent the `else` clause to match the indentation of the `if` statement.

Answer (score 1):

Your code contains some syntactic and semantic errors:

1. The boolean value `true` should start in capital letter `True`.
2. The way you write your code is very important, and should be formatted in the right way, the space before each instruction is sensitive i.e. the code in the same bloc should be preceded by the same number of space.
3. By using `raise` inside the `try` bloc, you created a custom exception that will always be executed and the `if` bloc will never be reached.
4. After the `except` key word you have two options:

   - Either to put the exception name, example:

   `except ValueError:
       print("Non-numeric data found in the file.")`

   - Or to not specify exception and let it blank

The correct way you should type your code is:

```
while True:
    hrs = input ("Enter no.of hrs worked: ")
    rate = input ("Enter the rate per hour: ")
    try:
        hrs = int(hrs)
        rate = int(rate)
        #raise ValueError("Non numeric value")
    except :
        print ('Non numeric data found.')
        continue    
    if hrs > 40:
        # anything over 40 hrs earns the overtime rate
        overtimeRate = 1.5 * rate
        overtime = (hrs-40) * overtimeRate
        # the remaining 40 hrs will earn the regular rate
        hrs = 40
        regular=hrs*rate
        total_pay=regular+overtime
        print(total_pay)
    else:
        # if you didn't work over 40 hrs, there is no overtime
        overtime = 0
        total_pay=hrs*rate
        print(total_pay)
    quit()
```

Hope it helps!

Comment: Well explained :)

Answer (score 0):

### A couple of mistakes...

You were missing a colon at the end of the `if statement`. Also, the `else` shouldn't be `indented`. Finally, I corrected your `try except` statement as you were raising the `ValueError` for no reason :). So now, if the inputs cannot be successfully converted to `ints`, then the `ValueError` will be raised and the `loop` will continue (if no error, then the code will continue and `break` out of the loop).

So the final code is:

```
while True:
    hrs = input ("Enter no.of hrs worked: ")
    rate = input ("Enter the rate per hour: ")
    try:
        hrs = int(hrs)
        rate = int(rate)
        break
    except ValueError:
        print("invalid entries")
        continue
if hrs > 40:
    # anything over 40 hrs earns the overtime rate
    overtimeRate = 1.5 * rate
    overtime = (hrs-40) * overtimeRate
    # the remaining 40 hrs will earn the regular rate
    hrs = 40
    regular=hrs*rate
    total_pay=regular+overtime
    print(total_pay)
else:
    # if you didn't work over 40 hrs, there is no overtime
    overtime = 0
    total_pay=hrs*rate
    print(total_pay)
```

Comment: The boolean value true should start in capital letter True.

Comment: @AbdelazizMirad oh yeah in my test doc I forgot I changed that thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

I think this is what your looking for:

```
while True:
    hrs = input ("Enter no.of hrs worked: ")
    rate = input ("Enter the rate per hour: ")
    try:
        hrs = int(hrs)
        rate = int(rate)
        break
    except ValueError as e:
        print (e)
        continue
if hrs > 40:
    # anything over 40 hrs earns the overtime rate
    overtimeRate = 1.5 * rate
    overtime = (hrs-40) * overtimeRate
    # the remaining 40 hrs will earn the regular rate
    hrs = 40
    regular=hrs*rate
    total_pay=regular+overtime
    print(total_pay)
else:
    # if you didn't work over 40 hrs, there is no overtime
    overtime = 0
    total_pay=hrs*rate
    print(total_pay)
quit()
```

Answer (score -1):

You should not use raise but just try except + use correct indentation (if an else) would be never used in your case (only while loop). Try version:

```
while True:
hrs = input ("Enter no.of hrs worked: ")
rate = input ("Enter the rate per hour: ")
try:
    hrs = int(hrs)
    rate = int(rate)

except ValueError as e:
    print (e)
    print("Non numeric value")
    continue
if hrs > 40:
    # anything over 40 hrs earns the overtime rate
    overtimeRate = 1.5 * rate
    overtime = (hrs-40) * overtimeRate
    # the remaining 40 hrs will earn the regular rate
    hrs = 40
    regular=hrs*rate
    total_pay=regular+overtime
    print(total_pay)
else:
    # if you didn't work over 40 hrs, there is no overtime
    overtime = 0
    total_pay=hrs*rate
    print(total_pay)
```